# Basis for polynomials of degree 2 or less (derivatives)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I want to find a basis $\mathbb{B}$ for $P_2$ such that

${p}_\mathbb{B}$ =  $
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    p(0) \\ p'(0) \\ p''(2)/2 
\end {bmatrix}$

are the coordinates for a second degree polynome $p$.

Since $p(0) = a$, $p'(0) = b$ and $p''(0)/2 = c$, I wonder if my basis is correct: (I assumed $P_2 = a+bx+cx^2$)

$\mathbb{B} =  
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end {bmatrix}$

Because $a*\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end {bmatrix} +b\begin{bmatrix} 
    0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end {bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix} 
    0 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end {bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a \\ b \\ c \end {bmatrix}$ which indeed is the result that I wanted. The derivates are kind of confusing though, I'm not sure if I've done this correctly.

Comment: To be very strict, note that $\mathbb{B}$ must be a basis of $P_2$, not of $\mathbb{F}^3$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying field). How would the corresponding basis elements look like?

Comment: I haven't learned anything about fields... I don't see what you mean by the corresponding basis elements

Comment: In my opinion @Diglett want to say that the base of $P_2$ is $\{1,x,x^2\}.$ Thus we have $$p(x)=ax^2+bx+c\implies p(x)=p(0)+p'(0)x+\frac{p''(0)}{2}x^2.$$

Comment: Oh, so the basis ${1, x, x^2}$ does actually give $[p]_\mathbb{B} = [a, b, c]$.. So that is the correct  basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Thanks for awarding me with the best answer, but I think the explanation was not perfect, so I found a better way. If you still like the old explanation better, then you can take a look at the "Edit History".

Our goal is it to find a basis of $P_2$ such that $$p_\mathbb{B} = \begin{bmatrix} p(0) \\ p'(0) \\ p''(0)/2 \end{bmatrix} $$

for **every** element $p$ in $P_2$.

Let $p = a + bx + cx^2$ an arbitrary element with coefficients $a,b,c$.
Since you have already shown us that $p(0)=a$, $p'(0) = b$ and $p''(0)/2 = c$, this means that we must find a basis $\mathbb{B}$ such that $$p_\mathbb{B} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}. $$

If we look at the standard basis $\mathbb{E} = \{ 1, x, x^2 \}$, we observe that

$$p_\mathbb{E} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix},$$

so $\mathbb{E}$ is a basis of $P_2$ which satisfy your condition.

We can also show that this is the **only** basis which satisfy this condition: We notice that $$ p_\mathbb{B} = p_\mathbb{E} = T(\mathbb{B},\mathbb{E}) p_\mathbb{B} $$
where $T(\mathbb{B},\mathbb{E})$ denotes the basis change matrix from $\mathbb{B}$ to $\mathbb{E}$. But since $T(\mathbb{B},\mathbb{E})$ is invertible, we see that $T(\mathbb{B},\mathbb{E})$ must be the identity matrix which is equivalent to $\mathbb{B} = \mathbb{E}$.